# Angular 6 Checkbox in td tag doesn't fire (change)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a angular project where I wish to check on the dynamic generated checkbox which are being checked however the (change) handler doesn't seems to fire

tickets.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let ticket of tickets; let i = index">
<td *ngIf="memberView">
<div class="custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" (change)="memberChange($event,ticket)" id="memberEvent{{i}}" class="custom-control-input -input-check" value="">
</td>
</tr>
```

tickets.ts

```
memberChange(event,ticket){
    console.log('onchange',ticket);
}
```

however the logging doesn't seems to fire at all, could someone help me with it

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: There is no problem in your shared code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-airmpq

Comment: thanks for creating the stackblitz pretty sure I messed up with some others script while generating the table that's probably why

Comment: If you fork it and create your not working demo, much easier to solve your problem :)

Comment: for some reason, the change is working when I bind it to the td tag, so I am doing so now event.target.checked but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Attribute value of the checkbox is not binded with any value

```
<tr *ngFor="let ticket of tickets; let i = index">
  <td *ngIf="memberView">
  <div class="custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="memberChange($event,ticket)" id="memberEvent{{i}}" class="custom-control-input -input-check" [value]="ticket">
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```